# How to multiply columns using the SQL dr?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am trying to multiply MontlySalary * BonusRate to calulate a Bonus column using the sql dr in a C# console app. When I run my code I get the following error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'MontlySalary * Bonus'
```

Here is my code:

```
 private static void ShowNewColumns()
    {
        try
        {

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string strID = "ID";
            string strFirstName = "FirstName";
            string strLastName = "LastName";
            string strBonus = "Bonus" ;
            string strTotal = "TotalComp";
            Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4}", strID.PadRight(10), strFirstName.PadRight(10), strLastName.PadRight(10), strBonus.PadRight(10), strTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("==========================================");
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //reading from the datareader          
                Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4}",
                    dr["ID"].ToString().PadRight(10),
                    dr["FirstName"].ToString().PadRight(10),
                    dr["LastName"].ToString().PadRight(10),
                    dr["MontlySalary * BonusRate"].ToString().PadRight(10),
                    dr["TotalComp"]);
            }
            dr.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("==========================================");

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // Display error        
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try ( dr["MontlySalary"] * dr["BonusRate"] ).ToString(), just be sure not retuning null values in query or try converting to Double, you can do this in the "Select" query too instead of doing in code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
dr["MontlySalary * BonusRate"].ToString().PadRight(10),
```

to

```
(Convert.ToDouble(dr["MontlySalary"]) * Convert.ToDouble(dr["BonusRate"]).ToString().PadRight(10)
```

or

```
 string sql = "SELECT *, MontlySalary * BonusRate salary FROM Employee";
 ....
 dr["Salary"].ToString().PadRight(10)
```